# Why is the compiler not using Numeric.plus in this case?

Tags: scala, generics

I am getting some (what seems to me) strange behavior when using the + method in a generic case class (below). The bottom method works fine, but the top one gives me an error for addVal - `type mismatch; found: DataT, required: String`.

I assume what is going on here is the compiler has converted `this.datum` into a String and so wants to use the `String.plus` method, whereas I want it to use the `Numeric.plus` method. Normally it would default to using the `Numeric.plus` method when presented with two `Numeric` instances so I'm not quite sure why it isn't in this case.

```
case class SingleValue[DataT <: Numeric[DataT]] (
    datum: DataT,
    ) {
  def addToDatumDoesntWork(addVal: DataT): SingleValue[DataT] = SingleValue[DataT](this.datum + addVal)
  def addToDatumWorks(addVal: DataT): SingleValue[DataT] = SingleValue[DataT](this.datum.plus(this.datum, addVal))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not invoking the `Numeric` type class the way it was intended.

```
case class SingleValue[DataT : Numeric](datum: DataT) {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  
  def addToDatumNowItWorks(addVal: DataT): SingleValue[DataT] = 
    SingleValue[DataT](this.datum + addVal)
}
```

It can also be done this way. (The two are roughly equivalent.)

```
case class SngleValue[DataT](datum: DataT)(implicit ev :Numeric[DataT]) {
  import ev._

  def addToDatumNowItWorks(addVal: DataT): SingleValue[DataT] =
    SingleValue[DataT](this.datum + addVal)
  // or
  def addToDatumWorks(addVal: DataT): SingleValue[DataT] =
    SingleValue[DataT](ev.plus(this.datum, addVal))
}
```

The idea is that you pull in the "evidence" that the proper implicit exists, then you can import what's needed for the infix notation.

Comment: thank you. I had not really thought about the distinction between SingleValue[DataT <: Numeric[DataT]] and SingleValue[DataT: Numeric] before. This question is actually part of a larger (though still not very large) issue I have been having for the past day or so - I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628278/using-a-generic-chosen-from-an-enumeration-of-types 
You seem to know your way round this topic well so if you could lend a hand there then I would be most grateful.