# Using a generic chosen from an enumeration of types

Tags: scala, generics

I've been grappling with this issue for the past 24 hours with little success, and already posted a couple of related questions, so apologies if anyone has seen it before. I think what I want to do is conceptually quite simple, and looks like this:

```
sealed trait DataType {
  type ElemT <: Numeric[ElemT] 
}
trait PositionsData extends DataType { type ElemT = Double }
trait WeightsData extends DataType { type ElemT = Double }

trait Error
case class TypeDoesntMatch() extends Error

case class DataPoint[T <: DataType] (
    point: T#ElemT
    ) { 
  def addToDataPoint(addTo: DataPoint[T]): Either[Error, DataPoint[T]] = 
    Right(DataPoint[T](this.point + addTo.point))
  // above method generates the error type mismatch; found: T#ElemT  required: String
  def addToDataPoint(addTo: DataPoint[_]): Either[Error, DataPoint[T]] = Left(TypeDoesntMatch()) 
}

// Example user behaviour - 
val d1 = DataPoint[PositionsData](1.1)
val d2 = DataPoint[PositionsData](2.2)
val d3 = DataPoint[WeightsData](3.3)

d1.addToDataPoint(d2) // should return Right(DataPoint[PositionsData](3.3))
d3.addToDataPoint(d2) // should return Left(TypeDoesntMatch())
```

The idea is to let the user of the library choose from a pre-defined list of (numeric) data types (the `DataType` trait) when creating (say) a  `DataPoint`. The author/maintainer of the library can then set exactly what numeric data type each `DataType` uses, away from the user's view.

So I'd like to define an enumeration (in the general sense) of `DataType`s, each with their own associated numeric type. I'd then like to be able to pass these to the DataPoint case class as a generic. The bits I'm having trouble with are

a) I can't figure out how to constrain `ElemT` to `Numeric` types only - the `<: Numeric[ElemT]` in the code below doesn't work, I think because, as others have pointed out, `Double` is not a subclass of `Numeric[Double]`.

b) I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to introduce the necessary implicit conversion so that `Numeric.plus` is used in `this.point + addTo.point`.

I'm not at all fussy about how I achieve this and if my approach looks totally wrong then I'd be happy to be told that. Sincere thanks to anyone who can help me escape this on-going type-mare.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to include some client code, i.e. your ideal of how this would be used.

Comment: @jwvh - thanks - I've updated the original post with an extra paragraph which hopefully adds a bit of clarity. If it's still not clear then do let me know.

Comment: So you've got a number of things going wrong here. You start with a recursive type definition, `type ElemT <: Numeric[ElemT]`, which isn't bad in and of itself, but it can't be overridden with a simple type: `type ElemT = Double`. Then it looks like you want to allow something like `DataPoint[WeightsData](n)` but only where `n` is the numeric type pre-selected for `WeightsData`. It would be clearer if you included example **code** as requested. Don't describe, demonstrate. Add examples instead of explanations.

Comment: @jvwh This is a fair comment - I've expanded the example a bit (the original wasn't very good) and included some example user code. I guess what I am trying to achieve here is that I would like to prevent the user adding a DataPoint[WeightsData] to a DataPoint[PositionsData], or at least have different behaviour if this occurs. The type alone obviously doesn't prevent this since they are both double.

Comment: @jwvh - just to make sure I'm understanding you - both d1 and d2 are instances of DataPoint (not DataType), so should hold a value in the .point field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the issues here, one solution might be to move the `Numeric` requirement to the same place as the `DataType` requirement (which is where the addition takes place anyway).

```
sealed trait DataType { type ElemT }
trait PositionsData extends DataType { type ElemT = Double }
trait WeightsData extends DataType { type ElemT = Double }

case class DataPoint[T <: DataType](point: T#ElemT
                                   )(implicit ev:Numeric[T#ElemT]) {
  import ev._
  def addToPoint(addTo: T#ElemT): DataPoint[T] =
    DataPoint[T](this.point + addTo)
}
```

This allows *some* type restrictions...

```
//       DataPoint[WeightsData]("2.2") <- won't compile
val dp = DataPoint[WeightsData](2.2)
dp.addToPoint(4.1)
//res0: DataPoint[WeightsData] = DataPoint(6.3)
```

...but it won't disallow numeric widening. (There's been some talk of removing this from the language, but, until then ...)

```
val dp = DataPoint[WeightsData](2) //Int
dp.addToPoint(48) //Int
//res0: DataPoint[WeightsData] = DataPoint(50.0) <- Double
```

---

**UPDATE**
With the updated user examples (kinda wish you had started with that info) my suggestion remains: Move the `Numeric` type restriction to the `DataPoint` class.

```
. . . //as before
case class DataPoint[T <: DataType](point: T#ElemT
                                   )(implicit ev:Numeric[T#ElemT]) {
  import ev._
  def addToDataPoint(addTo: DataPoint[T]): DataPoint[T] =
    DataPoint[T](this.point + addTo.point)
}

// Example user behaviour -
val d1 = DataPoint[PositionsData](1.1)
val d2 = DataPoint[PositionsData](2.2)
val d3 = DataPoint[WeightsData](3.3)

d1.addToDataPoint(d2)
//d3.addToDataPoint(d2)  <- won't compile
```

I don't see any advantage in logging a runtime error, via `Either[_,_]`, instead of a compile-time error. In fact, I think it would be both more difficult to achieve and less useful.

Comment: Yes - that seems perfect. Thank you very much indeed. And yes, this should be a compile-time error rather than a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of `Numeric`, as I understand, that it is just an implicit object and it looks like a typeclass and `Numeric[Double]` is a typeclass instance.

So you can place ElemT to type parameter and constrain it with context bound to `Numeric`:

```
case class DataPoint[ElemT: Numeric] (point: ElemT) {
    def addToPoint(addTo: ElemT): DataPoint[ElemT] = {
        val sum = implicitly[Numeric[ElemT]].plus(this.point, addTo)
        DataPoint[ElemT](sum)
    }
}
DataPoint(9.1).addToPoint(2.3)
```

Or if you for some reason still need `sealed trait DataType` with type member.
You can

```
sealed trait DataType {
    type ElemT
}
trait PositionsData extends DataType { type ElemT = Double }
trait WeightsData extends DataType { type ElemT = Double }

case class DataPoint[T <: DataType] (point: T#ElemT)(implicit numericInstance: Numeric[T#ElemT]) {
    def addToPoint(addTo: T#ElemT): DataPoint[T] = {
        val sum = numericInstance.plus(this.point, addTo)
        DataPoint[T](sum)
    }
}
DataPoint[PositionsData](9.1).addToPoint(2.3)
```

Comment: thank you - your comment about Numeric at the top actually clears up some of the confusion I've been having with it.